# How to solve sending data via ajax "Item is undefined: if (item.guid != null)" error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm writing this jquery script to send data to a php file via ajax. It works but I am getting this error. Can anybody tell me how I can solve this? The code is posted below so is the error.

Here is the error which I get after the data is sent.

> Item is undefined:   if (item.guid != null)

Here is the code:

```
// Data 
    dataObj = { correctAnswers: correctAnswers,                
               startTime:startTime,
               startDate:startDate 
               };

    //Post Data To contorler 
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "save",            
        data: dataObj,
        success: function(data) {
            //Need to return the file contents somehow!
            alert("Data sucessfully Sent\n");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Are you sure you have the right url? `save` and not `save.php`?

Comment: yes I do it's sending the data just keep getting this error what could possible be a cause of such error

Comment: `item` isn't mentioned in that code. The error must be coming from elsewhere.

Answer (score -1):

You need to specify that you are sending json to the server. You need to add the following option to your $.ajax

```
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
```

otherwise the function is expecting standard form post by default.

Comment: Which script is throwing this error. Your javascript or jquery? And do you get data to your PHP controller successfully ?

Comment: "You need to specify that you are sending json to the server" — Since the **aren't** sending JSON, that doesn't make sense.